# Best way to debug rspec integration tests with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I have an rspec test failing, but in development, when I perform the actions myself, the page renders correctly.

Here's the snippet:

```
describe "sign up process" do

let (:admin1) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

describe "with valid information"

  before do 
    visit new_admin_registration_path
    fill_in "Email", with: admin1.email
    fill_in "Password", with: admin1.password
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: admin1.password_confirmation
    click_button "Sign up"
  end

  it { should have_selector('div.alert') }
end
```

It's not finding that selector at all, but I confirmed it exists when viewing the source using the development environment.

What I'd like to be able to do is inspect the page that's rendering to see what I'm missing.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capybara has a method [`save_and_open_page`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara#save_and_open_page-class_method) which will open a new browser window with the current state of the page (it requires the `launchy` gem).

For example:

```
  before do 
    ...
    click_button "Sign up"
    save_and_open_page
  end
```

Comment: That is an incredibly useful method.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

this is as easy as using the debugger or something different like pry in your spec.

i personally prefer pry, cause installing the debugger was kind of a hassle everytime i tried it with ruby 1.9...

with pry you would just add a `require "pry"` in your spec_helper.rb and then write a `binding.pry` the line before the problem occurs. you then have an irb session attached to your test.

Comment: Very useful for debugging your tests. If you are doing integration tests with cucumber you should `require 'pry'` in the `/features/support/env.rb` file instead of the `spec_helper.rb`.